# R ts object format changes after train test splitting

Tags: r, time-series, training-data

I have a ts object

```
TorontoTempts <- ts(tempToronto$AvgTemperature, start=c(2015, 1), frequency=12)
```

I want to split it to train and test using subset:

```
train.ts <- subset(TorontoTempts, start = 1, end = 176)
testing.ts <- subset(TorontoTempts, start = 177, end = 200)
```

I did get the following error:

```
argument "subset" is missing, with no default
```

If works with the following code:

```
train.ts <- subset(TorontoTempts, subset=TRUE, start = 1, end = 176)
testing.ts <- subset(TorontoTempts,subset=TRUE, start = 177, end = 200)
```

However, when I want to pass it to tslm:

```
regModel <- tslm(train.ts ~ trend + season)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in tslm(train.ts ~ trend + season) : Not time series data, use lm()
```

Comment: I don't know of any version of the `subset` command that has start= and end= parameters. Are you using non-base R packages? Or are you following a guide somewhere? It looks like maybe the `forecast` package might support that syntax, just need to make sure to load that package first.

Comment: I agree with @MrFlick, it would be also good practice to prefix function calls with the package name such as `forecast::subset`

Comment: @John Manacup, `subset` is in base R -- it is only `subset.ts` that is in forecast and that is not exported for direct use -- it should be accessed via the generic, `subset`.  The code in your comment will result in an error. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`subset` has no ts method in base R.  You can

**1)** Use the forecast package which does have a subset.ts method:

```
tt <- ts(11:21, freq = 4) # test data

library(forecast)
subset(tt, start = 1, end = 3)
```

**2)** Convert to zoo and then use head, tail or subscripting and convert back.

```
library(zoo)

as.ts(head(as.zoo(tt), 3))

as.ts(as.zoo(tt)[1:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

For subsetting time series, R has the function `window`:

```
train.ts <- window(TorontoTempts, c(2015,1), c(2018,4))
```